# Ruby: adding to hash/ merging objects from YAML

Tags: ruby, hash, yaml

I have two YAML files that I have serialized.

"PP" comes from

```
ἀγαπάω:
  present: ἀγαπάω
  future: ἀγαπήσω
  aorist: ἠγάπησα
```

...many more...

"lexemes" comes from

```
ἀγαπάω:
    pos: V
    bdag-headword: ἀγαπάω
    strongs: 25
    gloss: I love
...many more...
```

I am trying to add the values for "gloss" and "strongs" to "pp", or otherwise merge pp values with these new ones from lexemes. Apparently ruby does not allow inserted of new values whilst iterating over a hash. So far I have:

```
pps = Hash.new
pp.each do |p|
lexemes.each do |lex, arr| 
  if lex.match /^#{p[0]}$/
    #match found
    puts "p #{p[0]} ... lex #{lex}...#{arr['strongs']}....#{arr['gloss']} .
  (pps[p[0]] ||= []) << p
  pps[p[0]].push(:strongs => arr['strongs'], :gloss => arr['gloss'])
  end
end
end
```

which when dumped yields:

```
"ἀγαπάω":
- - "ἀγαπάω"
  - present: "ἀγαπάω"
    future: "ἀγαπήσω"
    aorist: "ἠγάπησα"
- :strongs: 25
  :gloss: I love
```

when I really want:

```
ἀγαπάω:
  present: ἀγαπάω
  future: ἀγαπήσω
  aorist: ἠγάπησα
  strongs: 25
  gloss: I love
```

Any idea where/ how I should manage the insert of the new data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construction `||= []` is initializtion of an `Array`, just try to avoid it. And to merge two `Hash`es just use `#merge` method so:

```
h1 = { h1: { hh1: 1, hh2: 2}}
# => {:h1=>{:hh1=>1, :hh2=>2}}
h2 = { h1: { hh3: 3, hh4: 4}}
# => {:h1=>{:hh3=>3, :hh4=>4}}
h1[:h1].merge(h2[:h1])
# => {:hh1=>1, :hh2=>2, :hh3=>3, :hh4=>4}
```